# Create a dataframe from multiple list of dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code as below,

```
safety_df ={}
for key3,safety in analy_df.items():
    safety = pd.DataFrame({"Year":safety['index'],
                      '{}'.format(key3)+"_CR":safety['CURRENT'],
                      '{}'.format(key3)+"_ICR":safety['ICR'],
                      '{}'.format(key3)+"_D/E":safety['D/E'],
                      '{}'.format(key3)+"_D/A":safety['D/A']})
    safety_df[key3] = safety
```

Here in this code I'm extracting values from another dictionary. It will looping through the various companies that why I named using format in the key. The output contains above 5 columns for each company(Year,CR, ICR,D/E,D/A).

Output which is printing out is with plenty of NA values where after
Here I want common column which is year for all companies and print following columns which is C1_CR, C2_CR, C3_CR, C1_ICR, C2_ICR, C3_ICR,...C3_D/A ..

I tried to extract using following code,

```
pd.concat(safety_df.values())
```

Sample output of this..

[image]

Here it extracts values for each list, but NA values are getting printed out because of for loops?

I also tried with groupby and it was not worked?..

How to set Year as common column, and print other values side by side.

Thanks

Comment: Since `key3` will be different each time, your dataframes stores inside the `safety_df` dict will also be different: each dataframe differs, as they don't have the same columns.

Comment: Have a look at [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html).

Comment: You may also get a good result using the `axis` argument in `pandas.concat`, by setting it to concatenate along the columns instead (`axis=1`).

Comment: Note that you have a year with a value of `TTM`; is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `axis=1` to concate along the columns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

years = np.arange(2010, 2021)
n = len(years)
c1 = np.random.rand(n)
c2 = np.random.rand(n)
c3 = np.random.rand(n)

frames = {
    'a': pd.DataFrame({'year': years, 'c1': c1}),
    'b': pd.DataFrame({'year': years, 'c2': c2}),
    'c': pd.DataFrame({'year': years[1:], 'c3': c3[1:]}),
}
for key in frames:
    frames[key].set_index('year', inplace=True)

df = pd.concat(frames.values(), axis=1)
print(df)
```

which results in

```
            c1        c2        c3
year
2010  0.956494  0.667499       NaN
2011  0.945344  0.578535  0.780039
2012  0.262117  0.080678  0.084415
2013  0.458592  0.390832  0.310181
2014  0.094028  0.843971  0.886331
2015  0.774905  0.192438  0.883722
2016  0.254918  0.095353  0.774190
2017  0.724667  0.397913  0.650906
2018  0.277498  0.531180  0.091791
2019  0.238076  0.917023  0.387511
2020  0.677015  0.159720  0.063264
```

Note that I have explicitly set the index to be the 'year' column, and in my example, I have removed the first year from the 'c' column. This is to show how the indices of the different dataframes are matched when concatenating. Had the index been left to its standard value, you would have gotten the years out of sync and a NaN value at the bottom of column 'c' instead.